# Odoo V15, 500: Internal Server Error after move to new server | UserError: The attachment is colliding with an existing file

Tags: python, keyerror, internal-server-error, qweb, odoo-15

As first, thank you for help me, i am beginner in Odoo Website.

Since i have move on proxmox the website Odoo V15 to new Proxmox (same Website), the website shows me 500: Internal Server Error. Befor moving the website had works. The old server had works until Lightning strike, that's why I had to move the website.
How i had read, it is Key error and UserError with "The attachment is colliding with an existing file" -> But i dont understand what i need to in this case.

Here my log from Browser:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 85, in lookup
    r = d[key]
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 71, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 34, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj]
KeyError: ('ir.qweb', <function IrQWeb._generate_asset_nodes_cache at 0x7f72f72cb310>, 'web.assets_common', True, False, '', False, False, False, (1, 'de_DE'))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 219, in render_template
    yield from compiled_fn(self, values, log)
  File "<template_870>", line 377, in template_870
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 246, in _get_asset_nodes
    return self._generate_asset_nodes_cache(bundle, css, js, debug, async_load, defer_load, lazy_load, media)
  File "<decorator-gen-69>", line 2, in _generate_asset_nodes_cache
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 90, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 255, in _generate_asset_nodes_cache
    return self._generate_asset_nodes(bundle, css, js, debug, async_load, defer_load, lazy_load, media)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 266, in _generate_asset_nodes
    return remains + asset.to_node(css=css, js=js, debug=debug, async_load=async_load, defer_load=defer_load, lazy_load=lazy_load)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/assetsbundle.py", line 147, in to_node
    css_attachments = self.css(is_minified=not is_debug_assets) or []
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/assetsbundle.py", line 433, in css
    self.save_attachment(extension, css)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/assetsbundle.py", line 335, in save_attachment
    attachment = ira.with_user(SUPERUSER_ID).create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-228>", line 2, in create
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 391, in _model_create_single
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_attachment.py", line 25, in create
    return super(Attachment, self).create(vals)
  File "<decorator-gen-53>", line 2, in create
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 412, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, [arg])
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 621, in create
    values.update(self._get_datas_related_values(
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 257, in _get_datas_related_values
    values['store_fname'] = self._file_write(data, values['checksum'])
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 127, in _file_write
    fname, full_path = self._get_path(bin_value, checksum)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 112, in _get_path
    raise UserError("The attachment is colliding with an existing file.")
odoo.exceptions.UserError: The attachment is colliding with an existing file.
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 811, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 360, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 352, in checked_call
    result.flatten()
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1255, in flatten
    self.response.append(self.render())
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1248, in render
    return env["ir.ui.view"]._render_template(self.template, self.qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1975, in _render_template
    return self.browse(self.get_view_id(template))._render(values, engine)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 433, in _render
    return super(View, self)._render(values, engine=engine, minimal_qcontext=minimal_qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 29, in _render
    return super(IrUiView, self)._render(values=values, engine=engine, minimal_qcontext=minimal_qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1983, in _render
    return self.env[engine]._render(self.id, qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/tools/profiler.py", line 289, in _tracked_method_render
    return method_render(self, template, values, **options)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 76, in _render
    result = super()._render(template, values=values, **compile_options)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 134, in _render
    result = ''.join(rendering)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 221, in render_template
    raise e
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 219, in render_template
    yield from compiled_fn(self, values, log)
  File "<template_867>", line 20, in template_867
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 223, in render_template
    raise QWebException("Error when render the template", self, options,
Exception
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 811, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 360, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 352, in checked_call
    result.flatten()
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1255, in flatten
    self.response.append(self.render())
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 1248, in render
    return env["ir.ui.view"]._render_template(self.template, self.qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1975, in _render_template
    return self.browse(self.get_view_id(template))._render(values, engine)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 433, in _render
    return super(View, self)._render(values, engine=engine, minimal_qcontext=minimal_qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 29, in _render
    return super(IrUiView, self)._render(values=values, engine=engine, minimal_qcontext=minimal_qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1983, in _render
    return self.env[engine]._render(self.id, qcontext)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/tools/profiler.py", line 289, in _tracked_method_render
    return method_render(self, template, values, **options)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 76, in _render
    result = super()._render(template, values=values, **compile_options)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 134, in _render
    result = ''.join(rendering)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 221, in render_template
    raise e
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 219, in render_template
    yield from compiled_fn(self, values, log)
  File "<template_867>", line 20, in template_867
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 223, in render_template
    raise QWebException("Error when render the template", self, options,
odoo.addons.base.models.qweb.QWebException: The attachment is colliding with an existing file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 85, in lookup
    r = d[key]
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 71, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 34, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj]
KeyError: ('ir.qweb', <function IrQWeb._generate_asset_nodes_cache at 0x7f72f72cb310>, 'web.assets_common', True, False, '', False, False, False, (1, 'de_DE'))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 219, in render_template
    yield from compiled_fn(self, values, log)
  File "<template_870>", line 377, in template_870
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 246, in _get_asset_nodes
    return self._generate_asset_nodes_cache(bundle, css, js, debug, async_load, defer_load, lazy_load, media)
  File "<decorator-gen-69>", line 2, in _generate_asset_nodes_cache
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 90, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 255, in _generate_asset_nodes_cache
    return self._generate_asset_nodes(bundle, css, js, debug, async_load, defer_load, lazy_load, media)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 266, in _generate_asset_nodes
    return remains + asset.to_node(css=css, js=js, debug=debug, async_load=async_load, defer_load=defer_load, lazy_load=lazy_load)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/assetsbundle.py", line 147, in to_node
    css_attachments = self.css(is_minified=not is_debug_assets) or []
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/assetsbundle.py", line 433, in css
    self.save_attachment(extension, css)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/assetsbundle.py", line 335, in save_attachment
    attachment = ira.with_user(SUPERUSER_ID).create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-228>", line 2, in create
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 391, in _model_create_single
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/addons/website/models/ir_attachment.py", line 25, in create
    return super(Attachment, self).create(vals)
  File "<decorator-gen-53>", line 2, in create
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 412, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, [arg])
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 621, in create
    values.update(self._get_datas_related_values(
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 257, in _get_datas_related_values
    values['store_fname'] = self._file_write(data, values['checksum'])
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 127, in _file_write
    fname, full_path = self._get_path(bin_value, checksum)
  File "/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 112, in _get_path
    raise UserError("The attachment is colliding with an existing file.")
odoo.exceptions.UserError: The attachment is colliding with an existing file.
Error when render the template
UserError: The attachment is colliding with an existing file.
Template: website.layout
Path: /t/html/head/t[7]
Node: <t t-call-assets="web.assets_common" t-js="false"/>
```

Thank you for help so much!
Regards Pascal

I have reinstalled the template, no improvement.
Had checked network, proxy, SSL, all ok.
checked parameter: web.base.url = http://example.com

On the local IP 192.168.5.100 the website and the backend is running, no errors, only public is not.

EDIT: (/opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py):

`@api.model
def _get_path(self, bin_data, sha):
# retro compatibility
fname = sha[:3] + '/' + sha
full_path = self._full_path(fname)
if os.path.isfile(full_path):
return fname, full_path        # keep existing path

```
    # scatter files across 256 dirs
    # we use '/' in the db (even on windows)
    fname = sha[:2] + '/' + sha
    full_path = self._full_path(fname)
    dirname = os.path.dirname(full_path)
    if not os.path.isdir(dirname):
        os.makedirs(dirname)
    # prevent sha-1 collision
    if os.path.isfile(full_path) and not self._same_content(bin_data, full_path):
        raise UserError("The attachment is colliding with an existing file.")
    return fname, full_path

@api.model
def _file_read(self, fname):
    full_path = self._full_path(fname)
    try:
        with open(full_path, 'rb') as f:
            return f.read()
    except (IOError, OSError):
        _logger.info("_read_file reading %s", full_path, exc_info=True)
    return b''
```

`

Here is the Link for SQL Database dump from table "ir_attachment":
https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20230726XUqKCBW0 7.11MB

Comment: Could you please provide the content of the file: /opt/odoo15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py, near the Error: "The attachment is colliding with an existing file"

Comment: Hello Sylvain, thanks for help me. Shure.

Comment: Did you import your database content twice ? Could you provide def _same_content ?

Comment: No, only moved container from Proxmox A to Proxmox Server B, no import of data, not even from DB.`Where can I find "def _same_content"?

Comment: Sorry, I can't find a directory or content with "def_same_content". Have searched with find/locate without success. Can you give me more specific information on this?

Comment: in src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py:
    def _same_content(self, bin_data, filepath):
        BLOCK_SIZE = 1024
        with open(filepath, 'rb') as fd:
            i = 0
            while True:
                data = fd.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
                if data != bin_data[i * BLOCK_SIZE:(i + 1) * BLOCK_SIZE]:
                    return False
                if not data:
                    break
                i += 1
        return True

Comment: Could you provide an extract of your database-table ir_attachment ?

Comment: Download Link for ir_attachment i have added in description above. Thank you for help me!

Comment: Have you installed your odoo (database) with the option "include Demo data" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your ir_attachment database table, I have extracted some of the first columns : ID and file(name or binary)...
...and have found 4 different types of data:

```
1. url link to image files (jpg, png, icon) for website snippets...
2. images stored as binary
3. js files (for website assets...)
4. css files (for website assets...)
```

Could you recognize files that exist after the new odoo installation (before your importation) and files coming from your imported database ?

```
1   flag_image  \N  res.lang    flag_image
793 BTV_vektor.png  \N  website 
3   favicon \N  res.company favicon
544 s_banner_default_image.jpg  \N  ir.ui.view  
794 Film-Studio.jpg \N  ir.ui.view  
795 BTV_vektor.png  \N  ir.ui.view  
8   web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
9   web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
10  web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
11  web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
797 tripod-3364540.jpg  \N  ir.ui.view  
18  web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
19  image_1920  \N  res.partner image_1920
20  image_1024  \N  res.partner image_1024
21  image_512   \N  res.partner image_512
22  image_256   \N  res.partner image_256
23  image_128   \N  res.partner image_128
24  web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
25  web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
96  gift.jpg    \N  ir.ui.view  
97  mobile_device.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
98  mobile.jpg  \N  ir.ui.view  
99  office.jpg  \N  ir.ui.view  
100 ice_coffe.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
101 rocket.jpg  \N  ir.ui.view  
102 sell.jpg    \N  ir.ui.view  
103 shop.jpg    \N  ir.ui.view  
104 sign.jpg    \N  ir.ui.view  
105 sweet.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
106 wine.jpg    \N  ir.ui.view  
107 marketing.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
108 firework.jpg    \N  ir.ui.view  
109 s_background_image_01.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
110 s_background_image_02.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
111 s_background_image_03.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
112 s_background_image_04.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
26  image   \N  payment.icon    image
27  image   \N  payment.icon    image
28  image   \N  payment.icon    image
29  image   \N  payment.icon    image
30  image   \N  payment.icon    image
31  image   \N  payment.icon    image
32  image   \N  payment.icon    image
33  image   \N  payment.icon    image
34  image   \N  payment.icon    image
35  image   \N  payment.icon    image
36  image   \N  payment.icon    image
37  image   \N  payment.icon    image
38  image   \N  payment.icon    image
39  image   \N  payment.icon    image
40  image   \N  payment.icon    image
41  image   \N  payment.icon    image
42  image   \N  payment.icon    image
43  image   \N  payment.icon    image
44  image   \N  payment.icon    image
45  image   \N  payment.icon    image
46  image   \N  payment.icon    image
47  image_128   \N  payment.acquirer    image_128
48  image_128   \N  payment.acquirer    image_128
49  image_128   \N  payment.acquirer    image_128
50  image_128   \N  payment.acquirer    image_128
51  image_128   \N  payment.acquirer    image_128
52  image_128   \N  payment.acquirer    image_128
53  image_128   \N  payment.acquirer    image_128
54  image_128   \N  payment.acquirer    image_128
55  image_128   \N  payment.acquirer    image_128
56  image_128   \N  payment.acquirer    image_128
57  image_128   \N  payment.acquirer    image_128
58  image_128   \N  payment.acquirer    image_128
59  image_128   \N  payment.acquirer    image_128
60  image_128   \N  payment.acquirer    image_128
61  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
62  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
63  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
64  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
65  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
66  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
67  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
68  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
69  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
70  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
71  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
72  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
73  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
74  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
75  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
76  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
77  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
78  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
79  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
80  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
81  image_payment_form  \N  payment.icon    image_payment_form
82  web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
278 web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
546 image_1920  \N  product.template    image_1920
1210    web.assets_tests.js \N  ir.ui.view  
1209    web.assets_tests.js.map \N  ir.ui.view  
87  web.assets_backend_prod_only.min.js \N  ir.ui.view  
89  favicon \N  website favicon
90  business_conference.jpg \N  ir.ui.view  
91  bridge.jpg  \N  ir.ui.view  
92  deliver.jpg \N  ir.ui.view  
93  clock.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
94  manufacturing.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
95  compass.jpg \N  ir.ui.view  
113 s_background_image_05.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
114 s_background_image_06.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
115 s_background_image_07.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
116 s_background_image_08.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
117 s_background_image_09.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
118 header_image_1_default_image.jpg
119 s_cover_default_image.jpg
120 s_masonry_block_default_image_1.jpg
121 s_masonry_block_default_image_2.jpg
122 s_media_list_default_image_1.jpg
123 s_media_list_default_image_2.jpg
124 s_media_list_default_image_3.jpg
125 s_product_list_default_image_1.jpg
126 s_product_list_default_image_2.jpg
127 s_product_list_default_image_3.jpg
128 s_product_list_default_image_4.jpg
129 s_product_list_default_image_5.jpg
130 s_product_list_default_image_6.jpg
131 s_quotes_carousel_image_0.jpg
132 s_quotes_carousel_image_01.jpg
133 s_quotes_carousel_image_02.jpg
134 s_quotes_carousel_image_3.png
135 s_quotes_carousel_image_4.png
136 s_quotes_carousel_image_5.png
137 s_image_text_default_image.jpg
138 s_text_image_default_image.jpg
139 s_three_columns_default_image_1.jpg
140 s_three_columns_default_image_2.jpg
141 s_three_columns_default_image_3.jpg
142 s_carousel_default_image_1.jpg
143 s_carousel_default_image_2.jpg
144 s_carousel_default_image_3.jpg
145 s_picture_default_image.jpg
146 s_banner_default_image.jpg
147 s_parallax_default_image.jpg
148 s_reference_demo_image_1.png
149 s_reference_demo_image_2.png
150 s_reference_demo_image_3.png
151 s_reference_demo_image_4.png
152 s_reference_demo_image_5.png
153 s_reference_default_image_6.png
154 s_company_team_image_1.png
155 s_company_team_image_2.png
156 s_company_team_image_3.png
157 s_company_team_image_4.png
158 s_mega_menu_menu_image_menu_default_image.png
159 s_mega_menu_thumbnails_default_image_1.jpg
160 s_mega_menu_thumbnails_default_image_2.jpg
161 s_mega_menu_thumbnails_default_image_3.jpg
162 s_mega_menu_thumbnails_default_image_4.jpg
163 s_mega_menu_thumbnails_default_image_5.jpg
164 s_mega_menu_thumbnails_default_image_6.jpg
165 s_mega_menu_thumbnails_default_image_7.jpg
166 s_mega_menu_thumbnails_default_image_8.jpg
167 s_mega_menu_thumbnails_default_image_9.jpg
168 s_mega_menu_thumbnails_default_image_10.jpg
169 s_mega_menu_thumbnails_default_image_11.jpg
170 s_mega_menu_images_subtitles_default_image_1.jpg
171 s_mega_menu_images_subtitles_default_image_2.jpg
172 s_mega_menu_images_subtitles_default_image_3.jpg
173 s_mega_menu_images_subtitles_default_image_4.jpg
174 s_mega_menu_images_subtitles_default_image_5.jpg
175 s_mega_menu_images_subtitles_default_image_6.jpg
176 s_mega_menu_images_subtitles_default_image_7.jpg
177 s_mega_menu_menus_logos_default_image.jpg
178 s_mega_menu_menus_logos_default_logo_1.png
179 s_mega_menu_menus_logos_default_logo_2.png
180 s_mega_menu_menus_logos_default_logo_3.png
181 s_mega_menu_menus_logos_default_logo_4.png
182 s_mega_menu_menus_logos_default_logo_5.png
183 s_mega_menu_menus_logos_default_logo_6.png
184 s_mega_menu_cards_default_image_1.jpg
185 s_mega_menu_cards_default_image_2.jpg
186 s_mega_menu_cards_default_image_3.jpg
187 s_mega_menu_cards_default_image_4.jpg
188 s_mega_menu_cards_default_image_5.jpg
189 s_mega_menu_cards_default_image_6.jpg
190 s_mega_menu_cards_default_image_7.jpg
191 s_mega_menu_cards_default_image_8.jpg
192 s_product_catalog_default_image.jpg
193 s_blockquote_default_image.jpg
194 s_blockquote_cover_default_image.jpg
195 s_popup_default_image.jpg
196 web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
197 cover.png   \N  ir.module.module    
198 theme_default_screenshot.jpg    \N  ir.module.module    
279 web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
200 website.website_configurator_assets_scss.min.css    \N  ir.ui.view  
1182    website.assets_wysiwyg.css  \N  ir.ui.view  
799 BTV_vektor.png  \N  ir.ui.view  
202 web.assets_common_minimal.min.js    \N  ir.ui.view  
1212    web.assets_frontend.css \N  ir.ui.view  
203 web.assets_frontend_minimal.min.js  \N  ir.ui.view  
1181    website.assets_wysiwyg.css.map  \N  ir.ui.view  
816 web.pdf_js_lib.min.js   \N  ir.ui.view  
308 image_1920  \N  gamification.karma.rank image_1920
309 image_1024  \N  gamification.badge  image_1024
310 image_1024  \N  gamification.badge  image_1024
311 image_1024  \N  gamification.badge  image_1024
207 website.website_configurator_assets_js.min.js   \N  ir.ui.view  
312 image_1024  \N  gamification.badge  image_1024
313 image_512   \N  gamification.badge  image_512
314 image_512   \N  gamification.badge  image_512
315 image_512   \N  gamification.badge  image_512
316 image_512   \N  gamification.badge  image_512
317 image_256   \N  gamification.badge  image_256
318 image_256   \N  gamification.badge  image_256
319 image_256   \N  gamification.badge  image_256
88  logo    \N  website logo
421 test-pattern-152459.png \N  ir.ui.view  
233 web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
909 camera-775487_1920.jpg  \N  ir.ui.view  
796 BTV_vektor.png  \N  ir.ui.view  
800 hook-1425312.png    \N  ir.ui.view  
1211    web.assets_frontend.css.map \N  ir.ui.view  
1214    website.assets_editor.css   \N  ir.ui.view  
558 image_512   \N  product.template    image_512
234 s_media_list_default_image_1.jpg
235 s_media_list_default_image_2.jpg
236 s_media_list_default_image_3.jpg
237 s_company_team_image_1.png
238 s_company_team_image_2.png
239 s_company_team_image_3.png
240 s_company_team_image_4.png
241 s_reference_demo_image_1.png
242 s_reference_demo_image_2.png
243 s_reference_demo_image_3.png
244 s_reference_demo_image_4.png
245 s_reference_demo_image_5.png
246 s_reference_default_image_6.png
247 s_product_list_default_image_1.jpg
248 s_product_list_default_image_2.jpg
249 s_product_list_default_image_3.jpg
250 s_product_list_default_image_4.jpg
251 s_product_list_default_image_5.jpg
252 s_product_list_default_image_6.jpg
253 s_blockquote_default_image.jpg
254 s_blockquote_cover_default_image.jpg
255 s_masonry_block_default_image_1.jpg
256 s_masonry_block_default_image_2.jpg
257 web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
559 image_256   \N  product.template    image_256
320 image_256   \N  gamification.badge  image_256
321 image_128   \N  gamification.badge  image_128
322 image_128   \N  gamification.badge  image_128
323 image_128   \N  gamification.badge  image_128
324 image_128   \N  gamification.badge  image_128
1213    website.assets_editor.css.map   \N  ir.ui.view  
262 web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
798 hook-1425312.png    \N  ir.ui.view  
1186    web.assets_common.css   \N  ir.ui.view  
294 image_128   \N  im_livechat.channel image_128
1216    web.assets_tests.js \N  ir.ui.view  
295 web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
1185    web.assets_common.css.map   \N  ir.ui.view  
300 image_1920  \N  gamification.badge  image_1920
301 image_1920  \N  gamification.badge  image_1920
1215    web.assets_tests.js.map \N  ir.ui.view  
302 image_1920  \N  gamification.badge  image_1920
303 image_1920  \N  gamification.badge  image_1920
1042    reading-925589_1920.jpg \N  ir.ui.view  
304 image_1920  \N  gamification.karma.rank image_1920
305 image_1920  \N  gamification.karma.rank image_1920
401 web.assets_common_minimal.js    \N  ir.ui.view  
273 web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
306 image_1920  \N  gamification.karma.rank image_1920
307 image_1920  \N  gamification.karma.rank image_1920
400 web.assets_common_minimal.js.map    \N  ir.ui.view  
556 image_1920  \N  product.template    image_1920
403 web.assets_frontend_minimal.js  \N  ir.ui.view  
325 image_1024  \N  gamification.karma.rank image_1024
326 image_1024  \N  gamification.karma.rank image_1024
327 image_1024  \N  gamification.karma.rank image_1024
328 image_1024  \N  gamification.karma.rank image_1024
329 image_1024  \N  gamification.karma.rank image_1024
330 image_512   \N  gamification.karma.rank image_512
331 image_512   \N  gamification.karma.rank image_512
332 image_512   \N  gamification.karma.rank image_512
333 image_512   \N  gamification.karma.rank image_512
334 image_512   \N  gamification.karma.rank image_512
335 image_256   \N  gamification.karma.rank image_256
336 image_256   \N  gamification.karma.rank image_256
337 image_256   \N  gamification.karma.rank image_256
338 image_256   \N  gamification.karma.rank image_256
339 image_256   \N  gamification.karma.rank image_256
340 image_128   \N  gamification.karma.rank image_128
341 image_128   \N  gamification.karma.rank image_128
342 image_128   \N  gamification.karma.rank image_128
343 image_128   \N  gamification.karma.rank image_128
344 image_128   \N  gamification.karma.rank image_128
801 hook-1425312.png    \N  ir.ui.view  
402 web.assets_frontend_minimal.js.map  \N  ir.ui.view  
1218    web.assets_frontend_lazy.js \N  ir.ui.view  
1217    web.assets_frontend_lazy.js.map \N  ir.ui.view  
1190    web.assets_common.js    \N  ir.ui.view  
351 web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
354 web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
355 web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
372 S00001.pdf  \N  sale.order  
1189    web.assets_common.js.map    \N  ir.ui.view  
802 hook-1425312.png    \N  ir.ui.view  
916 photographer-3986846.jpg    \N  ir.ui.view  
1220    website.assets_editor.js    \N  ir.ui.view  
1219    website.assets_editor.js.map    \N  ir.ui.view  
1221    web.assets_common.min.css   \N  ir.ui.view  
1222    web.assets_frontend.min.css \N  ir.ui.view  
1223    web.assets_common_lazy.min.js   \N  ir.ui.view  
1224    web.assets_frontend_lazy.min.js \N  ir.ui.view  
969 Urheberrechtsvertrag.pdf    \N  ir.ui.view  
970 Nutzungsrechte-TV.Sender.Content.pdf    \N  ir.ui.view  
788 tripod-3364540.jpg  \N  ir.ui.view  
791 update.PNG  \N  ir.ui.view  
883 bitcoin-3585354_1920.jpg    \N  ir.ui.view  
887 druze-1388090_1920.jpg  \N  ir.ui.view  
551 image_1920  \N  product.template    image_1920
552 image_1024  \N  product.template    image_1024
553 image_512   \N  product.template    image_512
554 image_256   \N  product.template    image_256
555 image_128   \N  product.template    image_128
894 BTV_Logo-ohneClaim.gif  \N  ir.ui.view  
897 Kino-Business.Logo.gif  \N  ir.ui.view  
803 web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
1225    website.assets_editor.min.css   \N  ir.ui.view  
1226    website.assets_editor.min.js    \N  ir.ui.view  
382 web.assets_backend_prod_only.js \N  ir.ui.view  
381 web.assets_backend_prod_only.js.map \N  ir.ui.view  
560 image_128   \N  product.template    image_128
1227    web_editor.assets_wysiwyg.min.css   \N  ir.ui.view  
420 test-pattern-g91dce1720_1280.png    \N  ir.ui.view  
423 test-pattern-152459.png \N  website 
1228    web_editor.assets_wysiwyg.min.js    \N  ir.ui.view  
1229    website.assets_wysiwyg.min.css  \N  ir.ui.view  
1230    website.assets_wysiwyg.min.js   \N  ir.ui.view  
1184    website.assets_wysiwyg.js   \N  ir.ui.view  
1183    website.assets_wysiwyg.js.map   \N  ir.ui.view  
790 BTV_vektor.gif  \N  ir.ui.view  
792 BTV_vektor.png  \N  ir.ui.view  
571 web_icon_data   \N  ir.ui.menu  web_icon_data
1231    web.assets_frontend.min.css \N  ir.ui.view  
789 tripod-3364540.jpg  \N  ir.ui.view  
630 S00002.pdf  \N  sale.order  
1206    web.assets_backend.css  \N  ir.ui.view  
1205    web.assets_backend.css.map  \N  ir.ui.view  
1208    web.assets_backend.js   \N  ir.ui.view  
1207    web.assets_backend.js.map   \N  ir.ui.view  
4   image_1024  \N  res.partner image_1024
5   image_512   \N  res.partner image_512
6   image_256   \N  res.partner image_256
7   image_128   \N  res.partner image_128
854 clapboard-4489924_1280.png  \N  ir.ui.view  
882 laptop-3087585_1920.jpg \N  ir.ui.view  
885 laptop-3087585_1920.jpg \N  ir.ui.view  
888 bitcoin-3585354_1920.jpg    \N  ir.ui.view  
547 image_1024  \N  product.template    image_1024
548 image_512   \N  product.template    image_512
549 image_256   \N  product.template    image_256
550 image_128   \N  product.template    image_128
632 web.report_assets_common.css    \N  ir.ui.view  
631 web.report_assets_common.css.map    \N  ir.ui.view  
634 web.report_assets_common.js \N  ir.ui.view  
633 web.report_assets_common.js.map \N  ir.ui.view  
966 LeitfadenMASTER.pdf \N  ir.ui.view  
676 factur-x.xml
884 druze-1388090_1920.jpg  \N  ir.ui.view  
886 bitcoin-3585354_1920.jpg    \N  ir.ui.view  
889 druze-1388090_1920.jpg  \N  ir.ui.view  
890 businessman-3300907_1920.jpg    \N  ir.ui.view  
891 businessman-3300907_1920.jpg    \N  product.product 
557 image_1024  \N  product.template    image_1024
896 Kino-Business.Logo.png  \N  ir.ui.view  
1040    web.pdf_js_lib.js   \N  ir.ui.view  
1039    web.pdf_js_lib.js.map   \N  ir.ui.view  
1047    rubin.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
1151    web.assets_common.min.css   \N  ir.ui.view  
1152    web.assets_backend.min.css  \N  ir.ui.view  
1153    web.assets_common.min.js    \N  ir.ui.view  
1154    web.assets_backend.min.js   \N  ir.ui.view  
979 clapper-2140602.jpg \N  ir.ui.view  
1041    reading-925589_1920.jpg \N  ir.ui.view  
1044    rubin.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
1046    smaragd.jpg \N  ir.ui.view  
1137    invitation.ics
1138    invitation.ics
1043    smaragd.jpg \N  ir.ui.view  
1049    invitation.ics
1050    invitation.ics
1051    invitation.ics
1052    invitation.ics
1053    invitation.ics
1141    invitation.ics
1166    web.assets_common.css   \N  ir.ui.view  
1045    diamonds-2142417_1280.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
1048    diamonds-2142417_1280.jpg   \N  ir.ui.view  
1139    invitation.ics
1165    web.assets_common.css.map   \N  ir.ui.view  
995 web.report_assets_common.min.css    \N  ir.ui.view  
996 web.report_assets_common.min.js \N  ir.ui.view  
998 web_editor.assets_wysiwyg.min.css   \N  ir.ui.view  
999 web.assets_backend_legacy_lazy.min.css  \N  ir.ui.view  
1000    web.assets_backend_legacy_lazy.min.js   \N  ir.ui.view  
1172    web.assets_common_lazy.js   \N  ir.ui.view  
1171    web.assets_common_lazy.js.map   \N  ir.ui.view  
1140    invitation.ics
1017    web_editor.assets_wysiwyg.css   \N  ir.ui.view  
1016    web_editor.assets_wysiwyg.css.map   \N  ir.ui.view  
2   image_1920  \N  res.partner image_1920
1178    web_editor.assets_wysiwyg.css   \N  ir.ui.view  
1177    web_editor.assets_wysiwyg.css.map   \N  ir.ui.view  
1180    web_editor.assets_wysiwyg.js    \N  ir.ui.view  
1179    web_editor.assets_wysiwyg.js.map    \N  ir.ui.view
```

Comment: That exactly was the solution, thank you very much!!! First I deleted all duplicate inputs (except one entry), uploaded table back to database, restarted Odoo service and everything is back to normal.
I think the admin before installed the website with sample data, which led to these duplicate inputs. I myself had only made a copy of the website (copy Proxmox container) to a new server (then the problem appeared).

Sylvain, your input was the solution, you saved my week, thanks for that!!!